# AChartEngine in thread

Tags: achartengine

I'm using AChartengine in my project. I'm showing users charts with database data. 
I'm using actually 1.0.0 version of AChartEngine.

I wanted to change showing charts function in my app to threads.

Everything works but ... I've got a problem. Chart showed by runnable thread has no zooming possibilities.

On handler I've checked the GraphicalView if it is enabled. And it is. I tried so many options. Is this the AChartEngine issue?

I'm using this renderer options:

```
        renderer.setXLabels(7);
        renderer.setYLabels(10);
        renderer.setLegendHeight(60);
        renderer.setShowGrid(true);
        renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.CENTER);
        renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
        renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(false);
        renderer.setZoomEnabled(true);
        renderer.setExternalZoomEnabled(true);
        renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
        renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        renderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
        renderer.setMarginsColor(Color.WHITE);
        renderer.setChartTitle("");
        renderer.setMargins(new int[] { 15, AChartMarginLeft, 20, 15 });
        renderer.setPanLimits(new double[] { x.get(0)[0].getTime(),
                x.get(0)[(ileC - 1)].getTime() + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
                minvalY, maxY });
        renderer.setZoomLimits(new double[] { x.get(0)[0].getTime(),
                x.get(0)[(ileC - 1)].getTime() + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
                minvalY, maxY });
        renderer.setPointSize(4);
        renderer.setShowAxes(false);
        renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(AChartAxisTitleTextSize);
        renderer.setLabelsTextSize(AChartsetLabelsTextSize);
        renderer.setLegendTextSize(AChartsetLegendTextSize);
```

So zooming is enabled.

mChartView in handler is showing that mChartView has zoom enabled.

```
    private final Handler myHandler = new Handler();

final Runnable updateRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Log.d("updateRunnable","RUNNABLE");
        if (mRenderer.isZoomEnabled()) { 
        Log.d("ZOOM ENABLED","ENABLED");
        } else {
            Log.d("NO","NO ZOOMING");

        }
    }
};
```

**SOLUTION**

*Edit:*

I found answer to my question. I tried so many things. It wasn't zoom/pan margins.
I moved this part from thread to handler and now zooming works. If this part was in thread the chart was OK but like I said zooming hasn't been working.

```
mChartView = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(getApplicationContext(),
          ChartFunctions.buildBarDataset(titles, values), 
              renderer,type.DEFAULT);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting some zoom limits that seem to be exactly your chart values range. This means that you cannot zoom outside that range.

Comment: Hmm... the same code, without thread is working OK. The values are the same. But I'll check it. Maybe there is something wrong with this values. Thanks.

Comment: I've tried to change setZaoomLimits and setZoomLimits - no change. Zooming is not working at all.

Comment: I found the problem. I've moved one part of my function to handler and now it works.